# Auto voice reply to phone calls?

Tags: automation, voicemail

I'm looking for a way to automatically answer any incoming phone calls with a voice message, i.e. an autoresponder.

So actually much like voicemail, except I don't want people to leave me messages. I just want to play a welcome message or "I'm currently not available by phone" and refer them to my email address or Whatsapp.

Upon looking around I find tons of solutions which can auto respond by SMS, i.e. sending an auto reply text message. But that's not what I'm looking for, I prefer to play back a voice message.

Is there a way to do this, either natively from within Android or with an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible, you can record a greeting in the Google Voice app. Take a further look [here](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115069?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en). Hope that helps.

Comment: I've looked at Google Voice before, but unfortunately it says "Google Voice isn't supported in your country" 

Comment: My answer is correct but the law is making it impossible for you. Not fair enough. Hope you find a solution and my answer can help others too. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I'll mark your answer as correct, hoping that it helps someone else. Very frustrating that stupid regulations make this solution unavailable for me :(